# Download file using htmlunit button onclick

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I need to download a file  after button click, using selenium's htmlunit in java. The issue i am having is, after simulating the button click, the downloaded content returns the entire html instead of the actual file. Below are the steps i am following:

In my html/javascript,i have created the functionality to upload and download json using separate buttons as shown below. It works as expected in any web browser(chrome/firefox/ie)

upload button

```
 <button id="loadJson" class="button" onclick="$('#upload').click()" title="Reload JSON"></button> 
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form" style="display: none">
   <input id="upload" type=file accept=".json" name="files[]" size=30></form>
```

download button:(download dialogbox opens for specifying file name and save location)

```
<button id="saveJson" class="button" onclick="testUtil.save()" title="Save JSON"></button>
```

I am simulating the upload in htmlunit using the following code below:

```
   String webUrl="http://localhost:8000/";
    HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(webUrl);
    System.out.println(page.getByXPath(".//*[@id='upload']").get(0).toString());
    HtmlFileInput input =(HtmlFileInput) page.getByXPath(".//*[@id='upload']").get(0);
    input.setValueAttribute("C:\\My_files\\test.json");
```

Afterwards, I want to download the file i have uploaded,

```
HtmlButton button= (HtmlButton) page.getByXPath(".//*[@id='saveJson']").get(0);
System.out.println(button.toString());
```

to verify if i've selected the input: i see this as the output from the print statement above

```
    HtmlButton[<button id="saveJson" class="button" onclick="testUtil.save()"
 title="Save JSON">]
```

then i try to download and save :

```
InputStream is = button.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();  
byte[] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(buffer);
        File targetFile = new File("C:\\My_files\\new.json");
        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        outStream.write(buffer);
```

When i view the output file,it doesn't return the json,but it just returns the content of the html page(index.html). I am really not sure what i am missing.

Can anyone who has experience with selenium htmlunitdriver,please guide with debugging this issue?